# android: how once get location from gps?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have a button, clicking on it o need to get user current location from gps.

Can i do it without LocationListener?? cause i need to get position only after click action, and i neednt to eat battery by onLocationChanged all the time. 
is it possible?

i tried, but have error

```
public void goToHomePoint(View v){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);  
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + " " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

error

```
04-29 12:01:39.696: E/AndroidRuntime(252): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at com.artox.relax.inf.MapViewActivity.goToHomePoint(MapViewActivity.java:141)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252):  ... 19 more
04-29 12:01:39.716: E/AndroidRuntime(252): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Please include the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a LocationListener, but when your first receive a location, if the accuracy is what you want and stuff, you can then remove the same listener from the LocationManager with `removeUpdates`. You could even use a progress dialog while waiting for a location, and dismiss it when you have a location good enough to remove the location listener.

Answer (score 0):

This code I am trying out seems to work for me, it is the same as your code but the argument to getSystemService is `Context.LOCATION_SERVICE`

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

double lat = location.getLatitude();

double lon = location.getLongitude();
```

That said it seems to get a one-time location, although the location could potentially be old/outdated